# How to use numpy.vstack to append row to empty array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to append some rows of ndarray as values of dictionary. However, I receive an error for unequal dimensions using np.vstack. Please guide me in this regard.

```
dic = {0:[],1:[]}
point = np.array([[1,2],
                  [4,5],
                  [7,8]])
```

Desired Output: dic = {0: [[4,5]], 1: [[1,2],[7,8]]}

Below is the code I tried:

```
import numpy as np
dic = {0:[],1:[]}
point = np.array([[1,2],
                  [4,5],
                  [7,8]])

dic[0] = np.vstack([dic[1],point[1]])
dic[1] = np.vstack([dic[1],point[0]])
dic[1] = np.vstack([dic[1],point[2]])
```

Error:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 0 and the array at index 1 has size 3
```

Comment: Is point a list or a numpy array? What is the logic to select the rows? What is `arr`?

Comment: point is numpy array. Basically, I want to assign points in point to centroids in Kmeans Clustering so I am giving an simple example to just explain. Please inform how can I perform the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [424]: dic = {0:[],1:[]}
     ...: point = np.array([[1,2],
     ...:                   [4,5],
     ...:                   [7,8]])
     ...: 
     ...: dic[0] = np.vstack([dic[1],point[1]])
     ...: dic[1] = np.vstack([dic[1],point[0]])
     ...: dic[1] = np.vstack([dic[1],point[2]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-424-e3ba6811826c>", line 6, in <module>
    dic[0] = np.vstack([dic[1],point[1]])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in vstack
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 282, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 0 and the array at index 1 has size 2
```

Look at the elements of the `np.vstack([dic[1],point[1]])`.  One is a empty list, the other a (2,) shape array.  `np.array([])` is a (0,) shape array, hence the mismatch in shapes.  `vstack` needs to put equally sized array on top of each other.  Do not assume that the empty list works the same when working with arrays.

```
In [425]: dic[1]
Out[425]: []
In [426]: point[1]
Out[426]: array([4, 5])
```

We could define the initial `dic` elements as (0,2) shaped array.  Then they can be joined with (2,) or (1,2) arrays or even (n,2).

```
In [427]: dic = {0:np.zeros((0,2),int), 1:np.zeros((0,2),int)}
In [428]:      ...: dic[0] = np.vstack([dic[1],point[1]])
     ...:      ...: dic[1] = np.vstack([dic[1],point[0]])
     ...:      ...: dic[1] = np.vstack([dic[1],point[2]])
     ...: 
In [429]: dic
Out[429]: 
{0: array([[4, 5]]),
 1: array([[1, 2],
        [7, 8]])}
```

In general it's not a good idea of iteratively join arrays; getting dimensions right is tricky, and it is slower than list appends.

Using lists appends:

```
In [432]: dic = {0:[],1:[]}
     ...: dic[0].append(point[1])
     ...: dic[1].append(point[0])
     ...: dic[1].append(point[2])
In [433]: dic
Out[433]: {0: [array([4, 5])], 1: [array([1, 2]), array([7, 8])]}
In [434]: for k,v in dic.items():
     ...:     dic[k]=np.vstack(v)
     ...: 
In [435]: dic
Out[435]: 
{0: array([[4, 5]]),
 1: array([[1, 2],
        [7, 8]])}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you expect from `vstack`, but it looks like you're looking for simple slicing:

```
dic[0] = point[[1]]
dic[1] = point[[0,2]]
```

Output:

```
{0: array([[4, 5]]),
 1: array([[1, 2],
           [7, 8]])}
```